# can I change the text of month and day text from Android system?

Tags: android, localization, datetimepicker

so currently I am using [this library](https://github.com/florent37/SingleDateAndTimePicker) called SingleDateAndTimePicker to set the widget to pick date and time. like this

[image]

as you can see, the picker is in English. and that picker will follow the setting in Android phone. if the user sets the language in Indonesian then the day and month will be shown in Indonesian as well.

the problem is my app will only support one language. the user probably sets the language either in English or in Indonesian from their phone setting. so I want to force the user if their language is English, then I will still only show the Indonesian date time picker.

I know that to localize the string is through string.xml in a resource like this

```
<string name="Location">Lokasi</string>
```

but I need to know the `name` of the string of day and month, so I can force the English to Indonesian. can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried setting your apps default language to indonesian?

Comment: @sanjeev can I do that ? I am new in Android development. is it in manifest ?

Comment: yes you can.. All you have to do is force your language to indonesian by setting the app language..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to library documentation, You can change the localization using `customLocale(...)` like the following.

```
new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.Builder(this)
                .customLocale(Locale.GERMAN) // here you can customize locale
                .bottomSheet()
                .curved()
                .minutesStep(15)
                // .............
```

Comment: in my case, I use this code .setCustomLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("id")) . because Indonesian is not available as default. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can get the name of the string of day and month by using a calendar object and you can pass the Locale so it will return in that language.

Here is an example:

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 String displayName = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

In the above example, I have used `Locale.ENGLISH` you can pass your own language and it will return in the same language.

Comment: @sanjeev yes, you're right, he is using a library so he can not change the lib setting but he can get the desired string from the calendar and  set it to the lib calendar